# Adding keyframes in another thread while playing

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I'm having a problem here.

Suppose that you have a `Storyboard` object which controls a `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` object. At the beginning, the animation has only 100 frames.

There is a button, that in it's keypress, we want to play the storyboard. But, another thread is gonna started and in that thread, there are keyframes added to the animation. But, this does not occur. I mean, the frames *are added* but the storyboard ends when it reaches frame 100. and if you play the storyboard again, it has all frames added through the thread!!!

What do I do??

EDIT: in the `CurrentTimeInvalidated` Event of the storyboard, we have also the same problem. If you add frames there, they are not shown in the current animation, but if you replay, they are shown.

Answer (score 1):

`Storyboard` derives from `Freezable`. As far as I know you can't change `Storyboard` after it is started because a frozen clone will be animated.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. Now, is there anything possible that I can do for this kind of job??

Comment: You could try to play the Storyboard again but starting at the last played frame. But maybe Storyboard is not the right tool for this.

Comment: So what do you recommend? I have 28 simultaneous animations to handle. So I need sth fast. By the way, I have used ``CompositionTarget.Rendering`` Event, but it's not accurate. I mean it slows down and speeds up at different moments.